# Scrapy can not crawl link - comment of vnexpress website

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

I'm a newbie of Scrapy & Python. I try to get the comment from the following URL but the result always null : http://vnexpress.net/tin-tuc/oto-xe-may/toyota-camry-2016-dinh-loi-tui-khi-khong-bung-3386676.html

Here is my code :

```
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from tutorial.items import TutorialItem

import logging

class TutorialSpider(Spider):
    name = "vnexpress"
    allowed_domains = ["vnexpress.net"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://vnexpress.net/tin-tuc/oto-xe-may/toyota-camry-2016-dinh-loi-tui-khi-khong-bung-3386676.html"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        commentList = sel.xpath('//div[@class="comment_item"]')
        items = []
        id = 0;

        logging.log(logging.INFO, "TOTAL COMMENT : " + str(len(commentList)))

        for comment in commentList:
            item = TutorialItem()

            id = id + 1

            item['id'] = id
            item['mainId'] = 0
            item['user'] = comment.xpath('//span[@class="left txt_666 txt_11"]/b').extract()
            item['time'] = 'N/A'
            item['content'] = comment.xpath('//p[@class="full_content"]').extract()
            item['like'] = comment.xpath('//span[@class="txt_666 txt_11 right block_like_web"]/a[@class="txt_666 txt_11 total_like"]').extract()

            items.append(item)

        return items
```

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the comments are loaded into the page with some JavaScript code.

Scrapy does not execute JavaScript on a page, it only downloads HTML pages. Try opening the page with JavaScript disabled in your browser, and you should see the page as Scrapy sees it.

You have a handful of options:

- reverse-engineer how the comments are loaded into the page, using your browser's developer tools panel, in "network" tab (it could be some XHR call loading HTML or JSON data)
- use a (headless)browser to render the page (selenium, casper.js, splash...);

  - e.g. you may want to try this page with [Splash](https://splash.readthedocs.io/) (one of the JavaScript rendering options for web scraping). This is the HTML you get back from Splash (it contains the comments): http://pastebin.com/njgCsM9w

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will try it.